# How to assign a column's value to a variable?

Tags: mysql, variables

I want to set the `BalanceAmount` into a variable but it returns an empty value.

```
Declare BalAmt as int;
SET BalAmt = (SELECT BalanceAmount FROM mstragentrecharge);
SELECT BalAmt
```

Comment: Try start variable name with `@`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If this code is from function or procedure, then try below

```
Declare BalAmt as int;

SELECT BalanceAmount into BalAmt  FROM mstragentrecharge);

SELECT BalAmt
```

Or, for simple query:

```
SET @BalAmt  := '';
SELECT @BalAmt  := `BalanceAmount ` FROM mstragentrecharge limit 1;
SELECT @BalAmt FROM mstragentrecharge;
```

Comment: Thanks,Its working now i want to insert that value into table.how to pass the value in insert Query

Comment: @Vediyappan.V `insert into mstragentrecharge (BalanceAmount) values (@BalAmt)`